# what is meaning of this symbol lie in option $1$ ↓ and lie in option $2)↑$?

Tags: real-analysis

let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$be a sequence of continuous functions defined on $[0, 1]$

My   question  is that   what  is  meaning of  this  symbol lie in option $1$ ↓ ,lie in option $2)↑$

$1$.$f_n(x) ↓ f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1]$

$2.$ $f_n(x) ↑ f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1]$

Im  finding  difficulty  in understanding this  symbol ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a notation for monotone convergence. What is meant is that both $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for every $x\in[0,1]$ and (in case 1) $f_{n}(x)\ge f_{n+1}(x)$ or (in case 2) $f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x)$ for every $x\in[0,1]$.

So the symbol combines convergence and monotonicity. Other common symbols are $\nearrow$ and $\searrow$ instead of $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$.

Comment: thanks u kushma